In turbulent flow, where is the friction of the pipe exactly? Is it between the laminar layer and the pipe walls or the turbulent layer and laminar?
In turbulent flow as we get closer to the pipe walls we encounter an overlap layer and then a layer of laminar flow.
Also at the walls of a pipe, in turbulent flow, the laminar shear stress dominates. So essentially the shear stress both at laminar and turbulent is calculated by the same formula τ= μ*du/dy, at the walls
So when we talk about friction in the pipe walls in turbulent flow, between which layers exactly is this friction applied? Is it between the laminar layer and the wall, or between the turbulent layer and the laminar layer?
What confuses me is essentially this:
The shear stress at the wall for turbulent flow has the same formula as the shear stress at the wall for laminar flow, so that makes me think that this stress from the wall is applied to the laminar layer in the turbulent flow and not in the turbulent layer above.
And then i think that the shear stress is also used for the friction factor formula. But the friction factor is for the friction between the turbulent layer and the wall, or is it between the turbulent and the laminar layer actually?. Then the shear stress at the nominator of the friction factor should be the shear stress between the laminar and the turbulent, not the shear stress between the laminar layer and the wall.
$$
f \equiv \frac{\tau_w}{\rho\overline V^2/2}
$$

Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/818320/2451

what is the source of the equatiion

What is ambiguous about "at the walls"?
